# preg_replace does remove a group whereas it should use it inside the replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Given the raw string:

```
<p>my text 1</p>
some other content
<p>some other paragraph followed by an html line break</p><br>
etc...
```

which - let's assume - is the value of `$str`,

and the following treatment sequence :

```
$str=nl2br($str);
```

now we have:

```
<p>my text 1</p><br />
some other content<br />
<p>some other paragraph followed by an html line break</p><br><br />
etc...<br />
```

..., which is ok. Then :

```
$str=preg_replace('/(<\/p>)<br.{0,2}\/>/',${1}, $str);
```

I expect this code to remove all HTML `<br />`, `<br>`, or `<br/>` tags which are placed just after a closing `</p>`.

**How is it that php gives me :**

```
php > echo $str;
<p>my text 1
some other content<br />
<p>some other paragraphfollowed by an html line break</p><br><br />
etc...<br />
php >
```

**?**

**I'd rather expect :**

```
<p>my text 1</p>
some other content<br />
<p>some other paragraph followed by an html line break</p><br>
etc...<br />
```

Comment: Try `(<\/p>)<br ?\/?>` and it shouldn't be `${1}` but `$1`. Live demo https://regex101.com/r/GQRqit/1

Comment: @revo same thing with your suggestion / `$1`gives me this error :
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in php shell code on line 1`

Comment: Yes, you should enclose it in quotes. See answer below.

Comment: nice, it works :-) thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backreference used in replacement string is in a wrong format it shouldn't be `${1}` but `'$1'` (quoted!). Also by `<br.{0,2}\/>` you are not including `<br>` since you made one slash mandatory. Considering all above this is a solution:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(</p>)<br ?/?>~', '$1', $str);
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/ZrGUo)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are saying is:

1. You want to retain the pre-existing `<br>` tags and
2. Add a `<br>` tag where newline characters exist but are NOT preceded by a html tag (specifically to your sample input -- a `</p>`).

If this is the core of your coding intent, then you can omit the `nl2br()` step (and the subsequent mopping-up regex call) and just target the lines that end in text rather than a tag.

*If this doesn't work for your actual project, you'll have to adjust or explain the difference between your sample data and your actual data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/C7nov)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cU5LK0/1))

```
$string = <<<HTML
<p>my text 1</p>
some other content
<p>some other paragraph followed by an html line break</p><br>
etc...
HTML;

$string = preg_replace('~</?[a-z]+>\R(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|$~m', '<br>', $string);

var_export($string);                   // output
echo "\n----\n";
var_export(json_encode($string));      // encoded output (to show newline characters retained)
```

Output:

```
'<p>my text 1</p>
some other content<br>
<p>some other paragraph followed by an html line break</p><br>
etc...<br>'
----
'"<p>my text 1<\\/p>\\nsome other content<br>\\n<p>some other paragraph followed by an html line break<\\/p><br>\\netc...<br>"'
```

Essentially, I am arguing that you can do this task more directly.  Here is the pattern breakdown:

```
~               #start of pattern delimiter
</?[a-z]+>      #match less than symbol, optional forward slash, one or more letters, greater than symbol
\R              #match newline character(s)  ...you can add match one or more if suitable for your project
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)  #discard the characters matched (disqualify the match / do not replace)
|               #or
$               #the end of a line
~               #end of pattern delimiter
m               #multiline pattern modifier, tells regex to treat $ as end of line not end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$text = '<p>my text 1</p>
some other content
<p>some other paragraph followed by an html line break</p><br>
etc...';

$text = nl2br($text);

$regex= '#<\/p>(<br\s?\/?>)#';
$text = preg_replace($regex, '</p>', $text);
echo $text;
```

See how the regex matches here https://regex101.com/r/0gPhL3/1

Check the code working here https://3v4l.org/2RkFb